# Dynamics inputs, the v-model update all values in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for, v-model

I try this following code with Vue.js 2:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="items[index].message">
      <input type="text" v-model="items[index].surface">
    </div>    
  </div>
<button @click="addNewfield">Add</button>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    item: {
      message: 'test',
      surface: 45
    },
    items: [],
  },
  mounted() {
    this.items.push(this.item)
  },
  methods: {
    addNewfield() {
      this.items.push(this.item);
    }
  }
})
```

The goal is to create news input when user click on Add button. I tried different ways like :

```
<input type="text" v-model="item.message">
```

But it doesn't work. If you write in "message" input, all "message" inputs will be updated.

How can I only updated the concerned value ?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because objects in Javascript are stored by reference.  This means that every time you push `this.item` onto the array, it's adding a reference to the exact same object as the last.

You can avoid this by creating a new object each time:

```js
methods: {
  addNewfield() {
    const obj = {
      message: 'test',
      surface: 45
    } 
    this.items.push(obj);
  }
}
```

Another option would be to clone the original object each time like:

```js
methods: {
  addNewfield() {
    const clone = Object.assign({}, this.item);
    this.items.push(clone);
  }
}
```

Comment: Guy, You're awesome. Thanks for the explanation ! Have a good day